# Why does std::copy() require std::back_inserter to insert into a vector with sufficient capacity?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

**REFERENCE CODE:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::string label, std::vector<int> & arr) {
  std::cout << label << ":" << " size: " << arr.size() << " cap: " << arr.capacity() << " [ ";
  for (auto elem : arr) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  std::cout << " ] " << std::endl;
}

void reserve_dest_use_begin() {
  std::vector<int> s_arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
  print("source", s_arr);

  std::vector<int> d_arr;
  d_arr.reserve(3);
  print("dest", d_arr);

  auto min_elems = std::min(s_arr.size(), d_arr.capacity());

  std::cout << "COPYING FIRST" << min_elems << "3 FROM SOURCE TO DEST" << std::endl;

  std::copy(s_arr.begin(), s_arr.begin() + min_elems, d_arr.begin());

  print("source", s_arr);
  print("dest", d_arr);
}

void reserve_dest_use_back_inserter() {
  std::vector<int> s_arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
  print("source", s_arr);

  std::vector<int> d_arr;
  d_arr.reserve(3);
  print("dest", d_arr);

  auto min_elems = std::min(s_arr.size(), d_arr.capacity());

  std::cout << "COPYING FIRST" << min_elems << " ELEMENTS FROM SOURCE TO DEST" << std::endl;

  std::copy(s_arr.begin(), s_arr.begin() + min_elems, std::back_inserter(d_arr));

  print("source", s_arr);
  print("dest", d_arr);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "RESERVE DEST ARR. USE BEGIN() TO COPY" << std::endl;
  reserve_dest_use_begin();
  std::cout << "RESERVE DEST ARR. USE BACK_INSERTER() TO COPY" << std::endl;
  reserve_dest_use_back_inserter();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
RESERVE DEST ARR USE BEGIN() TO COPY
source: size: 6 cap: 6 [ 0 1 2 3 4 5  ] 
dest: size: 0 cap: 3 [  ] 
COPYING FIRST 3 ELEMENTS FROM SOURCE TO DEST
source: size: 6 cap: 6 [ 0 1 2 3 4 5  ] 
dest: size: 0 cap: 3 [  ] 
=============================================
RESERVE DEST ARR USE BACK_INSERTER() TO COPY
source: size: 6 cap: 6 [ 0 1 2 3 4 5  ] 
dest: size: 0 cap: 3 [  ] 
COPYING FIRST 3 ELEMENTS FROM SOURCE TO DEST
source: size: 6 cap: 6 [ 0 1 2 3 4 5  ] 
dest: size: 3 cap: 3 [ 0 1 2  ]
```

In both scenarios, the destination array has sufficient capacity. The documentation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) indicates:

```
Copies the elements in the range, defined by [first, last), to another range beginning at d_first.
1) Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and proceeding to last - 1. The behavior is undefined if d_first is within the range [first, last). In this case, std::copy_backward may be used instead.
```

The `d_arr.begin()` points to a range that is outside of the source range of `[first, last)`, but in the provided example, I need to use `std::back_inserter()` to copy instead of just providing `d_arr.begin()` despite the underlying vector having enough capacity.

Is the `std::back_inserter()` operation optimized to just memmove the block of memory, or is it pushing back every element? The note from cppreference indicates:

```
In practice, implementations of std::copy avoid multiple assignments and use bulk copy functions such as std::memmove if the value type is TriviallyCopyable and the iterator types satisfy LegacyContiguousIterator.
```

However, with `std::back_inserter()` I suspect it doesn't optimize with `memmove`.

In summary, I have the following questions:

1. Why can't I use `d_arr.begin()` as the `OutputIt` in `std::copy` when the underlying vector has sufficient capacity?
2. Is use `std::back_inserter()` optimized to bulk copy ranges?

**EDIT:**
I think I came at this question from the wrong angle. It has been clarified in the comments that the operation I want to do is `insert()` rather than `copy()`. My specific use case was that I repeatedly `clear()` my `d_arr` and copy a subvector from `s_arr` into `d_arr`. I am trying to avoid re-allocing my `d_arr`. However, since `d_arr` is cleared, and while it does have sufficient capacity, it has no size, meaning there are no elements to copy into. Instead, what I actually want to do is insert a subvector from `s_arr` into `d_arr`.

```
d_arr.insert(d_arr.begin(), s_arr.begin(), s_arr.begin() + min_elems)
```

Comment: Let me ask you: If you do `std::vector<int> d_arr;  d_arr.reserve(3);`, what is the `size()` of `d_arr`?

Comment: 1. `reserve()` is just for allocating, not for adding elements. You should use `resize()` instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver, In the output I posted you can see that if I reserve 3, the size is 0 and capacity is 3

Comment: Okay, so if the size is zero, then are there any elements in the vector for `std::copy` to copy into?

Comment: @MikeCAT wouldn't `resize()` default initialize the n elements in the vector? I just want to allocate the memory once and not default initialize all of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I see what you're getting at, the copy relies on elements to "overwrite". Is there a way I can just do the equivalent of a `memmove` aside from just using `memmove` itself?

Comment: your premise is wrong. I find it difficult to see where your misunderstanding is. Perhaps focus more on the output and what output you expect instead (rather than on your interpretation)

Comment: @ajoseps Nope.  When you use `reserve` you jut allocate memory, no actual objects (elements of the vector) are created.  You have to use vector's api to create them (like `push_back` which `back_inserter` uses.)

Comment: @NathanOliver so, in order to bulk copy from one vector to another, I need to use `resize()` on the `d_arr`, which in turns allocates and initializes the range I specify. I want to use this vector as a buffer, it might always be full, but it might not. I would need to essentially do my own tracking of "valid" elements if I want to be able to do this bulk copy (since the size to copy can be variable), otherwise, I would need to use the `back_inserter()` to insert and increase the size. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, to direct copy from one vector to another you just do `destination = source;`.  This will do a single allocation and copy all of the elements.  If you don't have a vector but another container that has begin and end iterators then you can make a copy like `vector_type destination{std::begin(source), std::end(source)};`  If you want to add elements to an existing vector, then use `insert` or `append` with the iterator range, that will also only do a single allocation if needed.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you that is helpful. In my use case I `clear()` my `d_arr` and then copy a subvector from `s_arr`. Instead of `copy` I should be just using `insert()`

Comment: @ajoseps That should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I use d_arr.begin() as the OutputIt in std::copy when the underlying vector has sufficient capacity?

Because the destination vector is empty, and thus `std::copy` overflows the vector (because assignment of any element is outside the bounds of an empty vector).

> Is the std::back_inserter() operation optimized to just memmove

It could be. It might even be optimised to something faster.

> Is use std::back_inserter() optimized to bulk copy ranges?

Given smart enough optimiser, yes.

---

Using the appropriate constructor of vector would be simpler than `std::copy`. Both for the reader of the code, and the optimiser.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps if I express a simple vector in code.

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    unsigned int size = 0;
    unsigned int capacity = 10;
    T* array = new T[10];

public:
    void push_back(T const& item) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            reserve(capacity * 2);
        }
        array[size] = item;
        ++size;
    }

    void reserve(unsigned int newCapacity) {
        if (size > capacity) {
            T* const temp = new T[newCapacity];
            std::copy(cbegin(), cend(), temp);
            delete [] std::exchange(array, temp);
            capacity = newCapacity;
        }
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) { return *array[i]; }

    // iterators
    T* begin() { return array; }
    T* end() { return array + size; }
    T const* cbegin() const { return array; }
    T const* cend() const { return array + size; }
};
```

What you see is that `reserve` does increase the allocated size for the vector, but is doesn't change the size!

When you are using the range-based for loop in `print`, the `begin` and `end` iterators are used, which internally use the size of the vectors. Thus not the whole internal array will be accessed.

And although writing to the array directly using a custom endpoint (`s_arr.begin() + min_elems`), with sufficient capacity to do so might not be 'illegal', its not good practice at all.

edit: what *does* changes the size of the vector is `resize`, which internally looks a little bit like this

```
    void resize(unsigned int newSize, T const& val = T{}){
        if (newSize > capacity) {
            reserve(newSize);
        }
        if (newSize > size) {
            std::fill(begin()+size, begin()+newSize, val);
        }
        size = newSize;
    }
```

Comment: I kind of like this but your answer is wrong.  When you do `new T[newCapacity]` not only do you increase the capcity, but you also increase the size as there are now `newCapacity` elements in the newed array.

Comment: @NathanOliver this is not an actual implementation, it is just indicative. I'm trying to show that `Vector::size` is not increased by a `reserve`, thus that `end() = array+size` used in the range-based for-loop will not see the new capacity. I was thinking of extending this with a `resize` function (also indicative)

Comment: @NathanOliver by the way, if you have suggestions for improvement, please feel free to change it. But I just want to keep it simple, for people learning the basics.